# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que dylimit() aparezca por encima de dygraph()?

Tags: r

Hay alguna forma de que en el gráfico me aparezca el `dylimit()` por encima del `dygraph()`? es decir que la linea roja se vea por encima de las barras. He estado buscando y tratando diferentes combinaciones pero no logro realizarlo.

Esto es lo que tengo
[image: Esto es lo que tengo]

Esto es lo que me gustaría tener
[image: Esto es lo que me gustaria tener]

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
dygraph((base1,"Titulo del grafico") %>% 
      dyAxis("y", label = "Porcentaje de cumplimiento", valueRange = c(0, 110)) %>% 
      dyAxis("x", label = "Mes y año", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
      dySeries(drawPoints = TRUE,label="Resultado", pointShape = "square", color = "lightblue",pointSize=2.5) %>%
      dyRangeSelector(dateWindow =     ds1.1.1[c(length(ds1.1.1)-12,length(ds1.1.1))]) %>%
      dyBarChart() %>% 
      dyLimit(95, "Mínimo permitido (95)", strokePattern = "solid", color =     "red")
```

Edito y agrego un ejemplo reproducible:

```
library("zoo")

a=c(0,0,0,7,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,3,0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,0)
b=c(597,619,639,622,613,591,632,611,596,598,558,542,567,556,595,543,597,617,543,596,636,386,336,349,376,318,329,339,304,309,301,321,308,472,344,292,389,306,282,312,313,376,315,327)
base1.1.1=cbind(a,b)

base1.1.1=ts(frequency = 12, start = c(2015, 10),base1.1.1)
ds1.1.1=as.Date(as.yearmon(index(as.zoo(base1.1.1)),"%mmm %Y"), frac = 0)

dygraph((1-(base1.1.1[,1]/base1.1.1[,2]))*100,"Titulo A") %>% 
  dyAxis("y", label = "Porcentaje de cumplimiento", valueRange = c(0, 110)) %>%  
  dyAxis("x", label = "Mes y año", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
  dySeries(drawPoints = TRUE,label="Resultado", pointShape = "square", color = "lightblue",pointSize=2.5) %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = ds1.1.1[c(length(ds1.1.1)-12,length(ds1.1.1))])  %>% 
  dyLimit(95, "Mínimo permitido (95)", strokePattern = "solid", color =     "red") %>% 
  dyBarChart()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema, es la línea punteada y el texto que aparecen debajo de las barras. **Hasta el momento no encontré forma de modificar este comportamiento, que en principio es solo para los gráficos tipo barcharts, en los gráficos de linea tipo el `dySeries()` funciona perfectamente**.

Una solución posible, es escribir en `javascript` nuestra propia función de plot de barras y agregarle a la misma la línea que queremos. La idea es algo así:

```
library("zoo")
library("dplyr")
library("dygraphs")
library("htmlwidgets")

minimo_permitido <- 95
myPlotter = JS(gsub("<<label>>", paste("Mínimo permitido (",minimo_permitido, ")"), 
                    gsub("<<ypos>>", minimo_permitido, "
            function barChartPlotter(e) {
               var ctx = e.drawingContext;
               var points = e.points;
               var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);

               // This should really be based on the minimum gap
               var bar_width = 2/3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
               ctx.fillStyle = \"lightblue\";
               ctx.strokeStyle  = \"lightblue\";

              // Do the actual plotting.
              for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                  var p = points[i];
                  var center_x = p.canvasx;  // center of the bar

                  ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
                  bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
                  ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
                  bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
              }

              var yPos=<<ypos>>;
              var width=points[points.length-1].canvasx;

              // Text
              ctx.fillStyle = \"red\";
              ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans';
              ctx.fillText('<<label>>', 90, e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(yPos)-5);

              // Dashed line
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.strokeStyle = \"red\";
              ctx.lineWidth = 3;
              ctx.setLineDash([15, 5]);

              ctx.moveTo(0, e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(yPos));
              ctx.lineTo(width, e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(yPos));
              ctx.stroke();

            }")))


dygraph((1-(base1.1.1[,1]/base1.1.1[,2]))*100,"Titulo A") %>% 
  dyAxis("y", label = "Porcentaje de cumplimiento", valueRange = c(0, 110)) %>%  
  dyAxis("x", label = "Mes y año", drawGrid = FALSE) %>% 
  dySeries(drawPoints = TRUE,label="Resultado", pointShape = "square", color = "lightblue",pointSize=2.5) %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = ds1.1.1[c(length(ds1.1.1)-12,length(ds1.1.1))])  %>% 
  dyOptions(plotter =  myPlotter)
```

Básicamente, generamos una función en `js` que se va a encargar de realizar todo el gráfico, barras y la línea punteada que queremos. La salida final es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: El código está basado en las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735999/dylimit-for-limited-time-in-dygraphs)

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, una consulta ya utilice la informacion que me dejaste en el comentario sin embargo no me grafica la linea, que puede ser?

Comment: Lamentablemente no tengo forma de saberlo, tendrías que  crear un ejemplo con datos y código que sea reproducible como para poder analizarlo.

Comment: Amigo, agregue al final del post el codigo para que sea reproducible. Le agradezco profundamente su tiempo y la ayuda que me ha estado dando. @Patricio-Moracho

Comment: @JRN, ahí edité tu pregunto y mi respuesta con algunos ajustes al código JS. Recuerda que debes configurar previamente la variable `minimo_permitido` al valor deseeado.

Comment: Excelente!!! Funciona y se ve como lo ocupaba, muchisimas gracias!